# Recomended read and write speeds for Ubuntu?

Tags: live-usb

I'm installing Ubuntu on a USB drive and it's super slow, i supuse that's because of the speed of the USB device but I wasn't able to find anywhere the recomendad write and read speed for Ubuntu does anyone know?

Comment: There is no official recommendation, other then "the higher the better". If possible, use USB 3.2 with 20Gbps speeds.

Comment: It is not the top read and write speed which matters, it's the read and write speed *for small operations*; a general read/write speed of 20 MB/sec is more than sufficient for normal use. Most flash drives have ridiculously low write speeds for small operations. If you test your devices with CrystalDiskMark for example, avoid trying to use a device which shows a write speed lower than, let's say, 0.5 or 1 MB/sec for "4K random" write operations.

Comment: @mikewhatever I've been googling **USB 3.2** and coming up empty. Do you have a link? The fastest I've found is USB 3.1 generation 2 (or USB type C). Having a Thunderbolt 3 on this new rig it would be fun (but not needed) to have a high speed USB thumb drive.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Here you go: https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2017/7/25/16026724/usb-3-2-usb-c-specification-charging-data-transfer-cables and https://techreport.com/news/32622/usb-3-2-spec-allows-for-20-gbps-over-existing-type-c-cables and http://www.trustedreviews.com/news/usb-3-2-care-3173569 ...

Comment: @mikewhatever Thanks very much for new reading material :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out what the Rufus developer said about USB speeds needed for another OS: https://superuser.com/a/1447105/35525